# ECB Never ask to make buffer read-only

Tags: find-file, echo-area, read-only-mode

In my current Emacs configuration, when ECB is active and I `find-file` in a non-existing directory, I keep getting interrupted to answer the following question in the echo-area:

`File /tmp/new-foo/bar.txt is read-only on disk.  Make buffer read-only, too? (y or n) n`

I would like to keep Emacs from interrupting me to type `y`/`n` whenever I open a new buffer. Sadly I can't find the ECB option that controls this.

What is the customisation option that controls this annoying behaviour?

Comment: Sounds like a bug if directory `new-foo` does not exist, unless you do not have write permission in `/tmp/`.

Comment: @Drew: unfortunately the problem happens anywhere and not just in tmp, folder to which I have write access anyway. The ECB codebase doesn't contain the string "Make buffer read-only" so I'm inclined to think this performed by some Emacs function.

Comment: Like I said, it sounds like a bug. Try contacting the ECB maintainer.

Comment: I was on an old git repo. The issue is subtly different in the latest master/HEAD, tracked in git issue https://github.com/ecb-home/ecb/issues/9